# How to calculate returns of a portfolio with rebalancing?

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, fama-french, portfolio-selection, rebalancing

I would like to compare the performance between a portfolio with the 30% of firms in S&P500 that have the highest ESG score to a portfolio with the 30% with the lowest ESG score. Then I would like to explain potential excess returns of the High-ESG portfolio by using the Fama-French 3 factor model + an additional factor that takes into account the ESG scores (high minus low ESG).
I would like to rebalance each of the 2 portfolios once a year according to the ESG score of the year before. The data on returns is monthly data.
I am using Stata for the analysis.
Now my questions: I started calculating the portfolio weights of each company for each year in my analysis.

1. How do I then calculate the monthly returns of each portfolio? Do I need to analyse the returns for each year separately?
2. What if a company is excluded from the index in the middle of a year?
3. How do I calculate a ESG high minus low factor similar to the other factors in the Fama French model?

Comment: These are three distinct questions, so they should be posted on three separate threads.